# RxJava2 connectable observable - replay not emitting all previous items

Tags: rx-java2

```java
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int j=1;j<=3;j++)
        list.add(j);


    Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.fromIterable(list)
    .replay()
    .autoConnect();



    observable.subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Integer integer) throws Exception {
            Log.v("consumer1:", ""+integer);
        }
    });


    observable.subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
@Override
public void accept(Integer integer) throws Exception {
    Log.v("consumer2:", ""+integer);

}
});



    observable.subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Integer integer) throws Exception {
            Log.v("consumer3:", ""+integer);
        }
    });
```

when i run the above code i get the following output:

```
consumer1:: 1
consumer1:: 2
consumer1:: 3
consumer2:: 1
consumer2:: 2
consumer2:: 3
consumer3:: 1
consumer3:: 2
consumer3:: 3
```

i was expecting replay to actually "replay" all the history that occurred before. so i was expecting to emit all the streams that occurred before.   specially this is the output i expected:

```
//first time nothing to replay so just do the work
consumer1:: 1
consumer1:: 2
consumer1:: 3

//replay consumer1 stream:,
consumer2:: 1
consumer2:: 2
consumer2:: 3
//already replayed now do the work
consumer2:: 1
consumer2:: 2
consumer2:: 3

//replay consumer1 stream:
consumer3:: 1
consumer3:: 2
consumer3:: 3

//replay consumer2 stream:
consumer3:: 1
consumer3:: 2
consumer3:: 3
//now do the work
consumer3:: 1
consumer3:: 2
consumer3:: 3
```

this is what i am expecting to happen with replay.  what am i doing wrong ? its like its not even working now the way i have it.

Comment: Each subscription is an individual connection into the cache. Why would it replay the cached items multiple times to the same consumer based on how many previous consumers there were?

Comment: its not the same consumer. i have used "new Consumer(...) "in each subscription.

Comment: Each subscription is an individual connection into the cache. Why would it replay the cached items multiple times to the same consumer based on how many previous consumers there were? –akarnokd. its not the same consumer. i have used "new Consumer(...) "in each subscription. – j2emanue

Comment: can you show me how to get what i want then ? what is the purpose of replay subject if it not replaying the previous emissions then ? how can this be achieved ?

Comment: It replays the items received by it, not the items it replayed to consumers. That doesn't make much sense and would lead to longer and longer sequences as more and more consumers will repeatedly get the same few items over and over. The 100th consumer would get 300 items with your expectation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you wanted this exotic behavior, but you can repeat with an ever increasing number:

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
    list.add(j);
}


AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

Observable<Integer> observable = 
    Observable.defer(() -> {
        Observable.fromIterable(list)
        .replay()
        .autoConnect()
        .repeat(count.incrementAndGet());
    });

observable.subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Integer integer) throws Exception {
        Log.v("consumer1:", ""+integer);
    }
});

observable.subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Integer integer) throws Exception {
        Log.v("consumer2:", "" + integer);
    }
});

observable.subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Integer integer) throws Exception {
        Log.v("consumer3:", ""+integer);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the difference between replay method and cache method in your answer?

Comment: i see. replay().autoConnect() is the equilent for cache() ..thanks